# Outer joins with ON conditions in JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, criteria, jpa-2.1

I need a criteria query for the following SQL query.

```sql
SELECT w.weight_id, w.weight, zc.charge
FROM weight w
LEFT OUTER JOIN zone_charge zc ON w.weight_id=zc.weight_id
AND zc.zone_id=?             <-------
ORDER BY w.weight ASC
```

The corresponding JPQL query would be like,

```sql
SELECT w.weightId, w.weight, zc.charge 
FROM Weight w 
LEFT JOIN w.zoneChargeSet zc 
WITH zc.zone.zoneId=:id      <-------
ORDER BY w.weight
```

I can't reproduce the same with criteria especially `WITH zc.zone.zoneId=:id`.

---

The following criteria query uses the `where` clause.

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder=entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple>criteriaQuery=criteriaBuilder.createTupleQuery();
Root<Weight> root = criteriaQuery.from(entityManager.getMetamodel().entity(Weight.class));
SetJoin<Weight, ZoneCharge> join = root.join(Weight_.zoneChargeSet, JoinType.LEFT);

ParameterExpression<Long>parameterExpression=criteriaBuilder.parameter(Long.class);
criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(join.get(ZoneCharge_.zoneTable).get(ZoneTable_.zoneId), parameterExpression));
criteriaQuery.multiselect(root.get(Weight_.weightId), root.get(Weight_.weight), join.get(ZoneCharge_.charge));
criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(root.get(Weight_.weight)));
TypedQuery<Tuple> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).setParameter(parameterExpression, 1L);
List<Tuple> list = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

How could it be modified so that it corresponds to `...LEFT OUTER JOIN zone_charge zc ON w.weight_id=zc.weight_id
    AND zc.zone_id=?`

This generates the following SQL query.

```sql
SELECT weight0_.weight_id  AS col_0_0_, 
       weight0_.weight     AS col_1_0_, 
       zonecharge1_.charge AS col_2_0_ 
FROM   social_networking.weight weight0_ 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN social_networking.zone_charge zonecharge1_ 
                    ON weight0_.weight_id = zonecharge1_.weight_id 
WHERE  zonecharge1_.zone_id =? 
ORDER  BY weight0_.weight ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `with` operator is a hibernate-specific extension to JPQL. You won't find support for it in the criteria API.

Comment: So, I must go with JPQL only?

Comment: Yes, HQL actually, since `with` is not a JPQL keyword.

Comment: Is it supported by Hibernate criteria? This query, in turn will be dynamic and query construction by string concatenation is by the way somewhat tedious.

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#createAlias%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20org.hibernate.criterion.Criterion%29

Comment: @Tiny I would like to know if JPQL is used instead of createQuery, how filter conditions will be processed? E.g. If my DAOImpl method receives any filter condition and if I would want to pass to JPQL as a parameter of filter condition, my query ought be `like %` can have performance issues isn't it?

Comment: It should be available in JPA provided by EclipseLink 2.4 which is still undergoing. Is it available there?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done along with the criteria API provided by [JPA 2.1](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/What_is_new_in_JPA_2.1%3F) using the new feature [*join `ON` clause*](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL#ON_.28JPA_2.1.29). Accordingly, the criteria query given in the question can be rewritten as follows.

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder=entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple>criteriaQuery=criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Tuple.class);
Root<Weight> root = criteriaQuery.from(entityManager.getMetamodel().entity(Weight.class));

ListJoin<Weight, ZoneCharge> join = root.join(Weight_.zoneChargeList, JoinType.LEFT);
criteriaQuery.multiselect(root.get(Weight_.weightId), root.get(Weight_.weight), join.get(ZoneCharge_.charge));

ParameterExpression<Long>parameterExpression=criteriaBuilder.parameter(Long.class);
join.on(criteriaBuilder.equal(join.get(ZoneCharge_.zoneTable).get(ZoneTable_.zoneId), parameterExpression));

criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(root.get(Weight_.weight)));
List<Tuple> list = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).setParameter(parameterExpression, 1L).getResultList();
```

It produces the following desired SQL query.

```sql
SELECT weight0_.weight_id  AS col_0_0_, 
       weight0_.weight     AS col_1_0_, 
       zonecharge1_.charge AS col_2_0_ 
FROM   social_networking.weight weight0_ 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN social_networking.zone_charge zonecharge1_ 
                    ON weight0_.weight_id = zonecharge1_.weight_id 
                       AND ( zonecharge1_.zone_id =? ) 
ORDER  BY weight0_.weight ASC
```

It should be worth mentioning that this query succeeds on Hibernate ([4.3.5 final](http://hibernate.org/orm/downloads/)) but the same query unexpectedly fails on EclipseLink ([2.5.1](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/)) with the following exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No parameter with name : Parameter[name=null] was found within the query: ReportQuery(referenceClass=Weight ).
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.setParameter(EJBQueryImpl.java:548)
    at admin.beans.ZoneChargeBean.getZoneChargeList(ZoneChargeBean.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4695)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:630)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4667)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4655)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    ... 72 more
```

`ParamterExpression` must be removed for it to work as follows.

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder=entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple>criteriaQuery=criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Tuple.class);
Root<Weight> root = criteriaQuery.from(entityManager.getMetamodel().entity(Weight.class));

ListJoin<Weight, ZoneCharge> join = root.join(Weight_.zoneChargeList, JoinType.LEFT);

criteriaQuery.multiselect(root.get(Weight_.weightId), root.get(Weight_.weight), join.get(ZoneCharge_.charge));
join.on(criteriaBuilder.equal(join.get(ZoneCharge_.zoneTable).get(ZoneTable_.zoneId), 1L));

criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(root.get(Weight_.weight)));
List<Tuple> list = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
```

**It should be an oversight in EclipseLink 2.5.1.**